# how to get out from loop with a single word

Tags: python

I have to make a program using `while` that:

1. Will ask for user to put 2 integer numbers
   and give back the addition and  multiplication
   of those 2.
2. Will check if the numbers are integers.
3. Will close if the user uses the word `stop`.

I have made 1 and 2 but am stuck on 3. Here is what I wrote:

```
while True:
    try:
        x = int(input("Give an integer for  x"))
        c = int(input("Give an integer for  c"))
        if  x=="stop":
            break


    except:
        print(" Try again and use an integer please ")
        continue

    t = x + c
    f = x * c
    print("the result  is:", t, f)
```

Comment: Your `if` will *always* be false (if `x` were `stop`, you'd get an exception when you try to convert it to an `int`).

Comment: _I have made 1 and 2 but am stuck on 3._ What is the issue with the program? Don't use a bare except like that, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948548/what-is-wrong-with-using-a-bare-except.

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't working because you are starting off by defining `x` as an integer, and for it to equal "`stop`", it needs to be a string.

What you therefore want to do is allow `x` to be input as a string, and then convert it to an integer if it isn't `stop`:

```
while True:
    try:
        x = input("Give an integer for  x")
        if  x=="stop":
            break
        else:
            x = int(x)
        c = int(input("Give an integer for  c"))



    except:
        print(" Try again and use an integer please ")
        continue

    t = x + c
    f = x * c
    print("the result  is:", t, f)
```

Comment: You don't really need the `else` (although it isn't wrong to use it).

Answer (score 0):

Just a slight change is required (and you can be slightly more structured using `else` in your `try` block.

You need to input the first value as a string so that you can first test it for "stop" and only then try to convert it to an integer:

```
while True:
    try:
        inp = input("Give an integer for x: ")
        if inp == "stop":
            break
        x = int(inp)
        c = int(input("Give an integer for  c: "))
    except:
        print("Try again and use an integer please!")
    else:
        t = x + c
        f = x * c
        print("the results are", t, f)
```

I have also fixed up some spacing issues (i.e. extra spaces and missing spaces in your strings).

Comment: How does the `else` help?

Comment: @ScottHunter It's not a big deal but you no longer have to have a `continue` statement in the `except` block and it more clearly shows the alternate code to be executed when you don't get an exception. In the end.